# Is $\frac{n}{\phi(n)}$ bounded if $\phi(n) = \phi(n+1)$?

Tags: number-theory, limits, prime-numbers, divisibility

Let $\phi(x)$ be the Euler totient function. Is $\dfrac{n}{\phi(n)}$ bounded if $\phi(n) = \phi(n+1)$? My experimental data for $n \le 10^{13}$ suggests that:

> **Claim**: If $\phi(n) = \phi(n+1)$ then,  $$\lim \inf \dfrac{n}{\phi(n)} \ge 2
> \text{, } \lim \sup \dfrac{n}{\phi(n)} < 3$$

Given below if the plot of all the $1,014$ solutions below $4.7 \times 10^9$

[image]

**Related Question:** [Conjecture on the gap between integers having the same number of co-primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3369378/conjecture-on-the-gap-between-integers-having-the-same-number-of-co-primes)

Comment: I wouldn't trust numerical data in this regard. One of $n$ and $n+1$ is odd—say $n$ for the sake of discussion—and it's quite hard at first for $n/\phi(n)$ to be large when $n$ is odd; but eventually the values of $n/\phi(n)$ are unbounded above even for odd $n$, and I see no reason to believe that coincidences of $\phi$ should avoid these.

Comment: Just to clarify : We only consider $\ n\ $ with $$\varphi(n)=\varphi(n+1)$$ and look at $$\frac{n}{\varphi(n)}$$ for those $\ n\ $, right ?

Comment: Solutions of $$\varphi(n)=\varphi(n+1)$$ are apparently very rare. Any reason to conjecture that the lim-inf is $\ 2\ $ ?

Comment: @Peter yes your understanding is correct. As of now, the lower bound is purely based on experimental data which as Greg commented may not be trust worthy. Anyways I have verified for about $2.5 \times 10^9$

Comment: @Peter The number of solutions seems to be growing at the rate $x^{0.31}$ so far

Comment: Solutions to $\phi(n) = \phi(n+1)$ are at https://oeis.org/A001274, which also gives the conjecture that $n$th solution is $a(n) ~ C*n^3*log(n)$ with $C = 9/\pi^2$.

Comment: @MichaelLugo This seems to be approximately consistent with my growth rate of the number of solution $\le x$ which in my data is about $x^{0.31}$.

Comment: @Nilotpal Kanti Sinha  I have a query that isn't really suitable as an independent question. In looking at the OEIS A001274 mentioned by Michael Lugo, I noticed that $$\phi(5186)=\phi(5187)=\phi(5188)=2592=2^53^4$$ Since you have looked at so many larger numbers, have you found other instances where $$\phi(n)=\phi(n+1)=\phi(n+2)$$

Comment: @KeithBackman 5186 is the solution so far. In fact I had posted that has a question earlier today and then deleted it since it was pointed out as a duplicate.

Comment: The OEIS-entry approves the conjecture very well. The maximum in the huge range checked is $2.494549$ , and after some minima that are a bit below $2$, the minima seem to approach $2$ from above.

Comment: @Peter Till what huge range did you check?

Comment: I mean the range checked by the author of the OEIS-link (upto $10^{13}$)

Comment: I did not check this range, but the entries in the OEIS-link indicate the correctness of the conjecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the lower bound, One of $n$ or $n+1$ is even.

If $n$ is even, then $\phi(n)/n\le 1/2$.

If $n+1$ is even, then $\phi(n+1)/(n+1)\le 1/2$.

Note that if $\phi(n)=\phi(n+1)$, then
$$
\left|\frac{\phi(n)}n -\frac{\phi(n+1)}{n+1}\right| = \frac{\phi(n)}{n(n+1)}.
$$

These prove the lower bound of the limit infimum.

Comment: How does this show a lower bound of $\frac{n}{\varphi(n)}$ ?

Comment: @Peter cause: $\frac {\phi(n)}{n} \le 1/2 \rightarrow 2 \le \frac{n}{\phi(n)}$

Comment: But $\frac{n}{\varphi(n)}\ge 2$ does not always hold if $\varphi(n)=\varphi(n+1)$ holds. For example, $n=65535$ is a counterexample, and one large counterexample can be found in the OEIS-link. Also, nothing is said about the value of the difference.

Comment: @Peter i guess your'e right and i didn't pay enough attention to it, sorry..

Comment: $\left|\frac{\phi(n)}n -\frac{\phi(n+1)}{n+1}\right| = \frac{\phi(n)}{n(n+1)}=O(\frac{1}{n})$, so we get that regardless which of $n, n+1$ is even,  $\phi(n)/n \le 1/2 + O(\frac{1}{n})$ and that implies indeed the lower bound when $n \to \infty$