# Conjecture on the gap between integers having the same number of co-primes

Tags: number-theory, limits, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Based on experimental data while analyzing the [related question posted here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3367767/is-fracn-phin-bounded-if-phin-phin1) I observed the following which I am presenting as conjectures.

> **Conjecture 1**: For every natural number $k$, the equation $\varphi(x) = \varphi(x+2k)$ has infinitely many solutions. Further, if $x = n$ is a solution then $\frac{n}{\varphi(n)}$ is bounded.
>
> **Conjecture 2**: The only solutions of $\varphi(x) = \varphi(x+3)$ are $x = 3,5$.

$\varphi(n)$ denotes the totient function.

Any reference to these in literature.

**Update**: I have verified conjecture 2 upto $n = 2 \times 10^8$.

Comment: If I recall, the first half of Conjecture 1 was made by Erdos. There's a reference in Guy's Unsolved Problems in Number Theory that may be relevant. My copy of UPINT is at home, but I'll try and look it up later today. If someone else has UPINT or knows of the relevant paper, they can chase it down before I do. For what it is worth, I'm skeptical of the second half of conjecture 1. Conjecture 2 seems plausible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my earlier comment I misremembered the author of the conjecture. The conjecture that is the first half of your conjecture 1 (that $\phi(n+2k)=\phi(n)$ has infinitely many solutions for any $k$ is due to Schinzel. The relevant entry in Guy's "Unsolved Problems in Number Theory" is B36 (in the third edition page 138-139). He lists two papers of Schinzel where this conjecture is discussed, both in Acta Arithmetica, one from 1958, the other from 1959. The full citations given by Guy (which I have not checked) are "A. Schinzel, Sur l'equation $\phi(x+k) = \phi(x)$, Acta Arithmetica, 4 (1958), 1818-184, MR 21 # 5597." and "A. Schinzel, A. Wakulicz, Sur l'equation $\phi(x+k) = \phi(x)$ II, Acta Arithmetica, 5 (1959), 425-426, MR 23, #A831."

Guy also mentions that Sierpinski proved that for any $k$, $\phi(n+2k)= \phi(n)$ has at least one solution. There's a bit connected to this and related problems in B36, so you should probably check the entry in the book out.

Answer (score 8):

Partial answer :

Conjecture $2$ is false : One of the entries in the OEIS-sequence in the linked question besides of $1$ is congruent $1$ modulo $3$. With the help of this entry I constructed $$n=9134280520365$$ which satisfies $$\varphi(n)=\varphi(n+3)$$

Comment: Good one. That settles it.

Comment: Is this the smallest counter example?

Comment: No idea, but I think we have very few solutions.

Comment: I think I found a stronger formulation of this conjecture for numbers of the form $6k+3$ having very less number of solutions compared to number of other form. The conjecture in this post was a special case for $k = 0$. I shall post this stronger formulation in a separate post.