# Rare gaps between integers having the same number of co-primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, conjectures

Let $\varphi(x)$ be the Euler totient function. For $k = 1,2,3,\ldots$ I calculated the number of solutions of $\varphi(x) = \varphi(x+k)$. I observed that we have very few solutions when $k = 3,9,15,21,\ldots$ and a very large number of solutions when $k = 6,12,18,24,\ldots$ as shown below for $n \le 10^7$.

[image]

**Question 1**: Why do we have a very few solutions when $k$ is an odd multiple of $3$ and a very large number of solutions when $k$ is an even multiple of $3$?

**Question 2**: Is the following claim true?

> For any six consecutive positive integer values of $k$, and a sufficiently large  $x$, the number of integers $n \le x$ such that $\varphi(n) = \varphi(n+k)$, is the lowest when $k \equiv 3 \text{ (mod 6)}$ and is the highest when $k \equiv 0
>  \text{ (mod 6)}$.

**Related question**: [Gap between integers having the same number of co-primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3369378/conjecture-on-the-gap-between-integers-having-the-same-number-of-co-primes)

Comment: We can even expect infinite many solutions for $\varphi(n)=\varphi(n+6)$ : Assume , $p$ is an odd prime such that $4p-3$ is prime as well. Then, we have $$\varphi(2\cdot (4p-3))=4p-4=4(p-1)=\varphi(8p)$$

Comment: @Peter Someone mentioned in the comments of the linked question that it is a conjecture of Erdos that there are infinitely many solutions for every even value of $k$.

Comment: Similar, if $p>3$ is prime such that $3p-2$ is prime as well, then $$\varphi(3\cdot (3p-2))=2\cdot (3p-3)=6\cdot (p-1)=\varphi(9p)$$

Comment: Finally, if $p>3$ is prime such that $2p-1$ is prime as well, than $$\varphi(2\cdot 3\cdot (2p-1))=2(2p-2)=4(p-1)=\varphi(12p)$$